# Canvas image rotation performance

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

**Image to help visualize code**

[image]

**Question**

Is there some way to make the code below even more performant? I feel like I'm missing something when it comes to only rendering the part of the image that's visible rather than the entire image.

**Code**

```js
// ------------
// Setup canvas
// ------------

let rotation = 0;
const ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth * ratio;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight * ratio;
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.scale(ratio, ratio);

// ----------
// Load image
// ----------

let imageReady = false;
const image = new Image();
      image.onload = () => {
        imageReady = true;
      }
      image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/ltOYsck.png';

// --------------
// Animation Loop
// --------------

window.requestAnimationFrame(loop)

function loop() {
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

  if (imageReady === true) {
    context.save();
    context.translate(canvas.clientWidth/2, canvas.clientHeight/2 + 1000)
    context.rotate(rotation * Math.PI / 180);
    context.drawImage(
      image,
      0,
      0,
      image.width,
      image.height,
      -image.width/4,
      -image.height/4,
      image.width * 0.5,
      image.height * 0.5
    );
    context.restore();
  }

  rotation += 0.1;
  if(rotation >= 360) rotation = 0;

  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: You could use one canvas instead of multiple canvas on top of each other. You should call requestAnimationFrame at the start of the loop so that you’re slightly less likely to miss a frame. You could probably use CSS animations for this. They are generally faster than JavaScript.

Comment: One minor - consider postponing your render loop until the image data has loaded, to avoid the `if (imageReady === true)` check every frame

Comment: Changing the size of a canvas is slightly faster than clearRect so you could increment and decrement the height (or assign the height to itself but I’m not sure if that will work).

Comment: @Kerndog73 Thank you for the tips. I tried keeping it straight CSS at first, but due to the size of the images and the style recalculations every frame it caused the rest of the UI to take a hit on performance (would see very slight lag every once in a while). I will look into using height to clear the canvas :)

Comment: @DacreDenny ah right! thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: No problems ! 

Comment: You could avoid calling save and restore by calling resetTransform instead. Everything I’ve mentioned so far are really just micro optimisations. I think the only way to really make this faster would be to use WebGL. If you’ve never used WebGL before then it might seem like overkill if all you want are some spinning images.

Comment: I’ve used OpenGL (not WebGL) before so I might be able to help you out if you decide to go down that path.

Comment: @Kerndog73 It looks like resetTransform isn't supported in Edge so I'll have to avoid it for the PC folks out there. I will spend some time tonight looking into WebGL to see if that will make things a little more performant. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: @Kerndog73 what are you saying? Wherever you call rAF it will get scheduled for the next frame, the position in the callback you call has absolutely no incidence whatsoever on whatever: no other external callbacks can be added in between since the code in cb gets executed synchronously. And now even worse, **changing the size of canvas is the slowest way to clear its context**. It will reset the whole context to defaults, reassign a new bitmap in memory and other slow stuff like that.

Comment: What performance issues are you actually having?

Comment: Is this your real image? Do you really need to draw it as an image? Drawing it as a path might improve perfs. Otherwise yes, a 4400×4400 image is slow to render, most graphic cards won't have enough memory to store it in their own cache.

Comment: @Kaiido I’m not quite sure what I was thinking when I made my comment about RAF. Maybe I thought it was asynchronous or something. I saw a benchmark for various methods for clearing the canvas and changing the size was fastest. Although, that was a couple of years ago so maybe things have changed. Now that you mention all of the things that happen when you resize, clearRect should be faster. That benchmark made no sense!

Comment: @Kaiido Found the old benchmark. https://jsperf.com/canvas-clear-speed/44 Assigning the width to itself is much faster than clearRect on my system.

Comment: @Kerndog73 didn't ran it yet but that benchmark proves nothing... There is nothing drawn on your context nor any properties of the context that has been modified. So yes resetting a clear canvas might be no-op, but, that's never what you do IRL.

Comment: @MattWaywhen stacking 5 canvases on top of each other with rotating images (4400 x 4400) spikes the Chrome CPU usage from 9% (4 canvases) to 70% (5 canvases). I assume this is due to the large images and lack of memory (I will attempt to cut them down). But other than that I was wondering if there is anything in the code above that could be done to optimize the way the image is being drawn/rotated with performance in mind.

Comment: @Kaiido It's a simplified version of the real image - the real one has a lot more details and is not just a path. I will spend some time tonight and see just how far I could cut the image down while still maintaining good quality. Are multiple canvases the way to go when trying to do the above 5x? And do you see anything wrong with the drawing/rotating code that could be improved? I noticed here they mention not to scale the image within the drawImage method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas#Don%E2%80%99t_scale_images_in_drawImage

Comment: What is it bout this 5 stacked canvases? I can't read anything about it in the question. This is a very bad idea indeed. Just do the stacking on a single canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "Answer" doesn't answer your question regarding your code, as I think it is the wrong approach in the first place ...

> I'm trying to achieve an effect with 4-5 canvases over each other all spinning at different speeds
>   However after 5 layers the CPU usage in Chrome goes through the roof (from 9% to 70%).

... but it includes an example that rotates **50** of your layers without problem. *~10%CPU and ~15%GPU; on a Laptop*

> The reason for the large images is because I want it to look crisp on Retina devices, so everything is twice as big as it needs to be (4400 x 4400)

Especially when you want a crisp image you avoid pixel graphics. The Image you use is perfect to convert it into a Vector.

4400x4400 Pixels means 4400x4400x4 Byte (~73MB) of raw image data that JS has to juggle around, every time you render (a part of) that image.

```js
/*
  // set random rotation speeds for each layer; and a bit more.
  // code is commented out, because at the moment this is defined in the CSS
  let i=1;
  for(let elm of document.querySelectorAll('#example>g')){
    // give this particular elm an initial rotation and add a little scale to it
    const sx = (Math.random() * .2 + .8).toFixed(4);
    const sy = (Math.random() * .2 + .8).toFixed(4);
    const rotate = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);

    const transform = `scale(${sx},${sy})rotate(${rotate}deg)`;
    const duration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25000 + 5000) + "ms";

    elm.style.setProperty("transform", transform);
    elm.style.setProperty("animation-duration", duration);

    console.log(`#example>g:nth-child(${i++}){animation-duration:${duration};transform:${transform}}`);
  }
*/
```

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#example>g>use {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: inherit;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  fill: rgba(64, 64, 64, .25);
}

/* the following CSS has been generated by the JS */
#example>g:nth-child(1){animation-duration:6235ms;transform:scale(0.9831,0.9672)rotate(317deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(2){animation-duration:27794ms;transform:scale(0.9849,0.8447)rotate(290deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(3){animation-duration:9000ms;transform:scale(0.8721,0.8287)rotate(149deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(4){animation-duration:13234ms;transform:scale(0.8428,0.8676)rotate(198deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(5){animation-duration:26854ms;transform:scale(0.9927,0.9902)rotate(136deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(6){animation-duration:20110ms;transform:scale(0.9047,0.8027)rotate(158deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(7){animation-duration:23603ms;transform:scale(0.9949,0.8478)rotate(32deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(8){animation-duration:27045ms;transform:scale(0.8898,0.8352)rotate(166deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(9){animation-duration:24821ms;transform:scale(0.8344,0.9232)rotate(127deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(10){animation-duration:11986ms;transform:scale(0.8612,0.8307)rotate(232deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(11){animation-duration:7464ms;transform:scale(0.8422,0.9567)rotate(175deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(12){animation-duration:6435ms;transform:scale(0.9263,0.8725)rotate(330deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(13){animation-duration:29691ms;transform:scale(0.9359,0.9489)rotate(260deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(14){animation-duration:12935ms;transform:scale(0.8948,0.9912)rotate(107deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(15){animation-duration:21544ms;transform:scale(0.8496,0.9085)rotate(120deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(16){animation-duration:16241ms;transform:scale(0.9520,0.8554)rotate(111deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(17){animation-duration:23578ms;transform:scale(0.8677,0.9682)rotate(234deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(18){animation-duration:15650ms;transform:scale(0.8582,0.8700)rotate(54deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(19){animation-duration:11847ms;transform:scale(0.9447,0.9884)rotate(139deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(20){animation-duration:9324ms;transform:scale(0.9153,0.9116)rotate(316deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(21){animation-duration:17702ms;transform:scale(0.9779,0.8993)rotate(37deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(22){animation-duration:13465ms;transform:scale(0.9961,0.8083)rotate(194deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(23){animation-duration:15226ms;transform:scale(0.9492,0.8862)rotate(183deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(24){animation-duration:12913ms;transform:scale(0.8593,0.9157)rotate(28deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(25){animation-duration:23357ms;transform:scale(0.9777,0.8756)rotate(118deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(26){animation-duration:6081ms;transform:scale(0.8035,0.8200)rotate(342deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(27){animation-duration:15580ms;transform:scale(0.8807,0.8166)rotate(242deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(28){animation-duration:18051ms;transform:scale(0.9160,0.8838)rotate(102deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(29){animation-duration:6058ms;transform:scale(0.8111,0.9906)rotate(3deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(30){animation-duration:8070ms;transform:scale(0.9133,0.8374)rotate(60deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(31){animation-duration:16621ms;transform:scale(0.8352,0.9580)rotate(339deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(32){animation-duration:27493ms;transform:scale(0.9611,0.8951)rotate(146deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(33){animation-duration:18659ms;transform:scale(0.8012,0.9420)rotate(234deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(34){animation-duration:26061ms;transform:scale(0.9279,0.8988)rotate(16deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(35){animation-duration:29827ms;transform:scale(0.9939,0.8191)rotate(289deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(36){animation-duration:20111ms;transform:scale(0.9248,0.8385)rotate(107deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(37){animation-duration:17507ms;transform:scale(0.8673,0.9479)rotate(330deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(38){animation-duration:12485ms;transform:scale(0.9069,0.9609)rotate(163deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(39){animation-duration:13963ms;transform:scale(0.8223,0.8398)rotate(195deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(40){animation-duration:9466ms;transform:scale(0.8756,0.9944)rotate(81deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(41){animation-duration:5128ms;transform:scale(0.8159,0.9781)rotate(118deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(42){animation-duration:19802ms;transform:scale(0.8892,0.9996)rotate(55deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(43){animation-duration:15241ms;transform:scale(0.8090,0.9250)rotate(169deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(44){animation-duration:17820ms;transform:scale(0.8080,0.8366)rotate(301deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(45){animation-duration:12900ms;transform:scale(0.8853,0.9383)rotate(298deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(46){animation-duration:27931ms;transform:scale(0.8182,0.9923)rotate(155deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(47){animation-duration:5307ms;transform:scale(0.9641,0.9780)rotate(299deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(48){animation-duration:12744ms;transform:scale(0.8974,0.9224)rotate(121deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(49){animation-duration:28452ms;transform:scale(0.8455,0.8270)rotate(125deg)}
#example>g:nth-child(50){animation-duration:7462ms;transform:scale(0.9797,0.9203)rotate(351deg)}
```

```html
<svg id="example" version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-2200 -2200 4400 1000">
  <defs><path id="asteroid" d="M-101 2154c-47-5-101-21-161-48-37-16-80-38-115-59l-19-11-19-5c-34-9-119-34-161-46-299-90-509-170-611-235-32-21-49-36-65-59-29-43-69-89-138-158-65-65-125-121-264-245-115-104-126-114-135-128-17-26-36-76-56-143-16-56-28-106-58-234-37-159-51-214-69-266-19-58-35-86-52-94-8-4-15-10-22-21-43-64-86-256-98-436-7-99-3-183 11-239 8-33 15-48 35-74 79-104 183-309 255-502 23-60 36-100 54-166 6-23 14-41 27-67 91-184 347-474 570-642 112-85 208-135 282-146 132-21 195-36 408-96 192-54 296-81 432-110 90-20 116-24 172-29 28-2.5 116-2.5 148 0 116 9 228 32 352 72 118 38 254 96 353 151l16 9 24 23c204 191 424 408 580 571 144 150 252 273 311 351 40 52 77 109 108 164 15 26 46 89 58 115 47 106 79 215 89 308 2.3 20 2 24-3.5 53-33 172-57 334-63 433-3 44-2.5 64 1.4 129 9 147 9 223 2 304-13 141-52 252-117 333-18 22-22 27-41 39-47 31-88 66-133 111-40 41-69 75-107 127-47 64-87 130-148 243-43 78-52 93-73 120-47 58-129 139-211 209-132 111-255 188-347 217-31 10-50 13-76 13-17 0-21-.3-30-2.3-35-8-52-10-94-10-37 0-54 1.1-89 6-89 12-189 40-292 81-47 18-147 49-219 67-53 13-92 21-134 27-20 3-56 3.5-73 1.5z"/></defs>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
  <g><use xlink:href="#asteroid" /></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question Thomas. And wow it looks like you're right - looks like vector is the way to go with this one.

Comment: You said the image couldn't be rendered as a path? If it can, then canvas will offer you about the same perfs as svg (https://jsfiddle.net/ecybd0mw/) Even if you do write SVG as vectors, it gets rasterized just the same when painted to screen.

Comment: @Kaiido nice, didn't know about Path2D. And last time I've worked with the canvas it didn't use the GPU *(there was something about that)*. Seems I have to get an update; thx.